# Spring logout problem

Tags: java, spring

I have an application which is validating only one user should use the application at a time. For that we are putting a column in DB table. By default the column value is 'Inactive'. When the user logged in, column value will be changed to 'active'. Once the user properly logged out, the column value will be changed to 'inactive' and the session gets an end. But when the user close the window improperly, the logout code is not working. I tried with onunload but the problem with the onunload is since we are using tiles, each time when we click a link log out is happening. So can anyone help me how to do it while closing the window directly?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You should not be keeping an entry in DB to track whether the user is online or not. Instead you have to keep all the user names in the application context and whenever the user logs in, you have to check if the user name is already in the application context. If not, add it to the context, else the user has already logged in.

Having a DB column to know if the user is active or not is a very bad idea. If at all this is used, you have to call an event using javascript every time you close the browser window. Also it might so happen that because of some network problem, the window close event will not be intercepted by the server resulting in the user being still shown as active in the DB

Comment: However, keeping logged in users in the application context means that you can't scale to multiple servers.